# Are there ways to use syncthreads in a conditional while loop in cuda?

Tags: cuda

Let's assume that there exist 64 threads per thread block.

Each thread runs following code:

```
int tid = threadIdx.x;

while (tid < 96) {
  // write data to shared memory
  __syncthreads();
  // read data from shared memory
  tid += 64;
}
```

In this case, the second run of while statement causes last 32 threads not to reach `__syncthreads()`, and I think this will result in undefined behavior.

Or, does __syncthreads() work correctly since last 32 threads reach the end of the code?

I currently can't find out how to solve this kind of problems.

Do I have to change algorithms?

Comment: "__syncthreads() is allowed in conditional code but only if the conditional evaluates identically across the entire thread block, otherwise the code execution is likely to hang or produce unintended side effects." ([CUDA Programming Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#synchronization-functions)) But TBH it does not feel like UB if the other threads return early.

Comment: It may not feel like, but it certainly is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Have all threads loop up to the same (maximum) value and encase the body of the loop excluding the `__syncthreads()` into another conditional checking the loop counter against the actual end value:

```
#define round_up(x, m) ((x) + (m) - 1 - ((x) + (m) - 1) % (m))

int tid = threadIdx.x;
int maxtid = round_up(96, blockDim.x) - 1;

while (tid <= maxtid) { 
  if (tid < 96) {
    // write data to shared memory
  }
  __syncthreads();
  if (tid < 96) {
    // read data from shared memory
  }
  tid += 64;
}
```

Comment: But won't that also potentially deadlock around threads exiting the outer loop?

Comment: @talonmies Do you still see a potential deadlock? I wonder if I miss something here.

Answer (score 0):

> __syncthreads()

causes undefined behavior or deadlock if not all of block threads step into it.

To scan a bigger-than-block-size space by a single block of threads,

```
copyLimit = 8192; // assuming 8k is going to be copied
w = blockDim.x; // this will be running inside copyLimit, nLoop times to fill all of it, but masked by some if-else to not overflow it
nLoop = copyLimit/w + 1;
for(int i=0;i<nLoop;i++)
{
     // load from global to shared
     if(threadIdx.x+i*w<copyLimit)
        doLoad();
}
__syncthreads(); // only once! A loading doesn't need sync with a loading.

for(int i=0;i<nLoop;i++)
{

     if(threadIdx.x+i*w<copyLimit)
     {
        // compute, assuming its just embarrassingly parallel
     }
}
// can also compute here too depending on compute job, to use all pipelines

for(int i=0;i<nLoop;i++)
{
     // save to global from shared
     if(threadIdx.x+i*w<copyLimit)
        doStore();
}
__syncthreads(); // only once!
// so that you can use stored values by other threads
doSomeWork(sharedArray);
```

If number of loop cycles per thread is unknown(like processing an unbalanced tree), then have a shared active counter.

```
active=1; // start working
while(active>0)
{
     // work
     if(!isFinished())
         doWork();         // sets isFinished() if it has no other job
      // any syncthreads or syncwarp whatever you need to sync
      __syncthreads(); // is not undefined behavior



     // when thread finishes its job, its not active
     if(isFinished())
         activeList[threadIdx.x] = 0;

     // reduction in a shared array, to find total number of active threads
     // and broadcast it to all threads 
     active=reduceActiveThreads(); // includes its own syncthreads    
}
// all block threads exit here together, as soon as last thread completes its job
```

You can also try warp version of it, to lessen the lost-cycles in idle threads in loop, if there is a Volta+ architecture in reach.(counting on independent thread scheduling of it). Even without Volta, the warp reduction can be faster than shared array reduction.

If number of cycles for all threads are same but unknown in compile-time, then finding max of all should be enough. Then using it to loop for that amount of times for all threads of block makes no undefined behavior.

```
int nLoop = findNumCycles(threadIdx.x, someParameters);
nLoop = reduceN(nLoop, threadIdx.x); // max(of all nLoop values)
for(int i=0;i<nLoop;i++)
{
     // can synchronize block now
     __syncthreads();
}
 // or here, only once, if there was only a loading from global into shared
 __syncthreads();
```